# Apply authentication in etherpad lite

Tags: authentication, etherpad

How can we prevent the etherpad lite pads to be accessed by public. Is there any way that we can prevent the unauthorised access to the etherpads. Only the users with username and password must have access to the pads.

I am using etherpad lite on windows.
Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to configure this in the settings.json of your etherpad. The original configuration is well documented.

Here is the part of the configuration you should taking care of.

```
  /* Users must have a session to access pads. This effectively allows only group pads to be accessed. */
  "requireSession" : true,

  /* Users may edit pads but not create new ones. Pad creation is only via the API. This applies both to group pads and regular pads. */
  "editOnly" : false,

  /* How long may clients use served javascript code (in seconds)? Without versioning this
     may cause problems during deployment. Set to 0 to disable caching */
  "maxAge" : 21600, // 60 * 60 * 6 = 6 hours

  /* This is the path to the Abiword executable. Setting it to null, disables abiword.
     Abiword is needed to advanced import/export features of pads*/  
  "abiword" : null,

  /* This setting is used if you require authentication of all users.
     Note: /admin always requires authentication. */
  "requireAuthentication": true,

  /* Require authorization by a module, or a user with is_admin set, see below. */
  "requireAuthorization": true,

  /* Users for basic authentication. is_admin = true gives access to /admin.
     If you do not uncomment this, /admin will not be available! */
  /*
  "users": {
    "admin": {
      "password": "changeme1",
      "is_admin": true
    },
    "user": {
      "password": "changeme1",
      "is_admin": false
    }
  },
  */
```

Comment: So if I set `"requireAuthentication": true`, can I share my pad?

Comment: I found that the above solution did not work in my instance.  After some googling and some trial and error. I only modified:

`"requireAuthentication": true,`

The other values dealing with authorization and session can be left alone:
`"requireAuthorization": false,`
`"requireSession": false,`

Comment: I am also going to paste the link to the answer I gave somewhere else for anyone who is googling "etherpad basic authentication" (like i was) and landed here. I wrote up what finally fixed my situation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70399416/1741264